# Downcasting viewholder

Tags: java, android

I have came across this code where viewholder was cased and I can't understand the reason why I have checked casting in java and from what I understood this is some sort of downcasting, yet I can't understand why casting viewholder here is the code

```
public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
  {
    ViewHolder localViewHolder;
    if (paramView == null)
    {
      paramView = ((LayoutInflater)this.activity.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(this.row, null);
      localViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      paramView.setTag(localViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
     // here is my confustion in why cast viewholder 
      localViewHolder = (ViewHolder)paramView.getTag();
    }
    if (this.itemsCategory != null)
    {
      if (paramInt + 1 > this.itemsCategory.size()) {
        return paramView;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the tag is an arbitrary object that belongs to the View. You can set it to other objects than ViewHolder but this pattern uses ViewHolder hence, It should be casted to ViewHolder.

Comment: From my understanding we use casting to assign one data type to another or one object to another since Java does not permit to assign a super class object to a subclass object we need explicit casting or downcasting ,is this the case in casting ViewHolder ?

Comment: The tag is of type Object but its actually a ViewHolder and you need to convert it "back" to ViewHolder to unhide its ViewHolder properties. Upcasting happens automatically but downcasting must be manually conducted by the programmer, this line in this case // paramView.setTag(localViewHolder);

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me please why did we need to use this line of the code 
             localViewHolder = (ViewHolder)paramView.getTag();

Comment: To get the ViewHolder from the view by casting the tag in order to set its properties (missing in your code)